# Stored procedure with Alembic: MySQL Syntax Error

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, alembic, sqlalchemy-migrate

I am using Alembic to load a stored procedure into the MySQL database. Following the [cookbook](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/cookbook.html), I was able to create the required objects for creating and dropping the procedure. Now that I want to upgrade the version to actually load the procedure, I am getting SQL syntax near the `DELIMITER $$` which I need for procedure definition. I have also tried to remove the `DELIMITER` and replace `AS` for starting the procedure, but that didn't work either. I even tried the simple example function in the cookbook, but that also gave me the same syntax error near `$`.

```
class ReplaceableObject:
    def __init__(self, name, sqltext):
        self.name = name
        self.sqltext = sqltext


class ReversibleOp(MigrateOperation):
    def __init__(self, target):
        self.target = target

    @classmethod
    def invoke_for_target(cls, operations, target):
        op = cls(target)
        return operations.invoke(op)

    def reverse(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @classmethod
    def _get_object_from_version(cls, operations, ident):
        version, objname = ident.split(".")

        module = operations.get_context().script.get_revision(version).module
        obj = getattr(module, objname)
        return obj

    @classmethod
    def replace(cls, operations, target, replaces=None, replace_with=None):

        if replaces:
            old_obj = cls._get_object_from_version(operations, replaces)
            drop_old = cls(old_obj).reverse()
            create_new = cls(target)
        elif replace_with:
            old_obj = cls._get_object_from_version(operations, replace_with)
            drop_old = cls(target).reverse()
            create_new = cls(old_obj)
        else:
            raise TypeError("replaces or replace_with is required")

        operations.invoke(drop_old)
        operations.invoke(create_new)


@Operations.register_operation("create_sp", "invoke_for_target")
@Operations.register_operation("replace_sp", "replace")
class CreateSPOp(ReversibleOp):
    def reverse(self):
        return DropSPOp(self.target)


@Operations.register_operation("drop_sp", "invoke_for_target")
class DropSPOp(ReversibleOp):
    def reverse(self):
        return CreateSPOp(self.target)


@Operations.implementation_for(CreateSPOp)
def create_sp(operations, operation):
    operations.execute(
        """
        DELIMITER $$
        CREATE PROCEDURE %s %s
        DELIMITER ;
        """ % (
            operation.target.name, operation.target.sqltext
        )
    )


@Operations.implementation_for(DropSPOp)
def drop_sp(operations, operation):
    operations.execute("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS %s" % operation.target.name)
```

And this is how I'm trying to create it:

```
my_procedure = ReplaceableObject(
    "my_procedure(IN arg1 TEXT, IN arg2 TEXT, OUT res TEXT)",
    """
    BEGIN
        -- procedure implementation
    END $$   
    """
)

def upgrade():
    op.create_sp(my_procedure)

def downgrade():
    op.drop_sp(my_procedure)
```

And this is the error (I'm using `pymysql` as client):

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$\n        CREATE PROCEDURE my_procedure(IN arg1 TEXT, IN arg2 TEXT, OU' at line 1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `DELIMITER` except in an environment that supports a series of semicolon-separated statements — the MySQL client.

In fact, the `DELIMITER` command is a [mysql client builtin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html), and it's not recognized by the MySQL Server.

You must not use `DELIMITER` when submitting statements to the MySQL Server through an API, even if it's `CREATE PROCEDURE`.